# pluralNoun + "are" + "a/an" + singleNoun

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, singular

Today a sentence hit my mind :

> Processes are an integrated set of ....

vs :

> Processes are integrated sets of ....

to an EnglishLanguageLearner the second one feels more valid, because we hear everyday **a/an** is not used with with(after) plural nouns. But what I am trying to say is about **a single set** containing of **plural processes**.

WHICH ONE IS CORRECT?

Thanks Everyone :-nice_smile

Comment: I'm not sure either choice is the best way of phrasing this. Please can you give the whole sentence you would like to say? As to a general answer to your question, yes you _can_ use the pattern plural noun + plural verb + singular noun. In many cases, however, I find that it sounds awkward and would be better if phrased differently.

Comment: Thanks @SteveES here is the whole sentence : "Processes are an integrated set of activities that are done in order to achieve a single objective." I'll be happy if I learn a better way for saying this : )

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, if you can explain it in more detail that would be helpful. Do you mean that each individual process is made up of a set of activities? Or that multiple processes are integrated into a set of activities? Or something else entirely?!

Comment: WHOOOOOOOOOOO.... seeing your comment made me fix my mindset. +100.  Actually it is documentation of a software. It has something to do with some BPMN charts. It Doesn't matter. I was trying to imply a set containing of some activities. Each set is a process. So Processes are more than a set. Now I see.. I should simply just say "Processes are integrated sets of activities that are done to ..." . right ? 

Thanks @SteveES . It was so helpful and life-saving. : )

Comment: Just to double-check... Does your statement applies to all processes individually (rather than all processes together, or only some processes; would it be equally true to say _a process is..._ about any process)? Also, do you mean 1 process = 1 set of activities; 1 process = multiple sets of activities; or 1 process = (at least) 1 set of activities + some other stuff?

Comment: WOW! That opens a door to lots of things. I like how you are "DETAILSISTIC". : ) - YES! my statement applies to all process individually, meaning each process is a set of activities (and YES) among other things. e.g.: 1 process = 1 set of activities + some other "minor"  stuff. I love to know where it goes, but by the way I think I will go with "Processes are integrated sets of activities ...".  Thanks .

Comment: I would advise being as precise and unambiguous as possible in technical documentation. I would therefore advise using _"Each process is..."_ or _"Each process consists of..."_, as this makes it clear that it applies to _all_ processes, while also allowing you to clearly state what a _single_ process involves. Saying "Processes are integrated sets..." leaves it ambiguous as to whether a single process contains 1 set, or contains multiple sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know if you wish to implicate a singular sense or a plural one into the word **"Processes"**

- *Processes are an integrated set of ...* - You see the **Processes** as a single set (one group, union).
- *Processes are integrated sets of ...* - You see **Processes** as multiple sets (groups, unions)

Having in mind your comment *"But what I am trying to say is about a single set containing of plural processes."* the first instance is correct.